# Does the little-oh relation remain if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both integrate or differentiate?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

> Give two functions $f$ and $g$ with derivatives in some interval containing 0,where $g$ is positive.Assume also $f(x)=o(g(x))$ as $x \to 0$. Prove or disprove each of the following statements:
>
> (a) $\int^x_0 f(t)dt = o(\int^x_0g(t)dt)$ as $x \to 0$
>
> (b) $f'(x)=o(g'(x))$ as $x \to 0$

I use the definition to prove (a) 
$$\begin{align}  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\int^x_0 f(t)dt}{\int^x_0 g(t)dt} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\int^x_0 \frac{f(t)}{g(t)}g(t)dt}{\int^x_0 g(t)dt} \\ &=  \lim_{x \to 0}  
\frac {f(c)}{g(c)} \frac{\int^x_0 g(t)dt}{\int^x_0 g(t)dt} \;\;\;\text{(c is between 0 and x)}\\ &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {f(c)}{g(c)} 
\end{align}$$
$c \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ ,so the limit is $0$.

I tried to prove (b) by using $k(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $f'(x)=g'(x)k(x)+k'(x)g(x)$ then$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g'(x)k(x)+k'(x)g(x)}{g'(x)} \\ &= \lim_{x \to 0} (k(x) + \frac{ k'(x)g(x)}{g'(x)})\end{align}$$  I am not able to deal with second term.It seems I'm not doing in a right way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that (b) is not true. Take $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)$ a function such that $|f(x)|\le x^2$ but $f'(x_n)= 1$ on some sequence $x_n\to 0$. Clearly $f(x) \in o(x)$ but $f'(x)=1$ frequently so $f'\not \in o(1)$.

An explicit example is given by $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ which has derivative $f'(x) = 2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)$. Notice that $f(x)/x \to 0$ (as $x\to 0$) but $\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x)$ does not exist since $f'(x_k) \to -1$ for $x_k = 1/(2\pi k)$.

Comment: hi,the question gives "f and g with derivatives in some interval containing 0",I think it means $f'(0)$ exists.But the $f(x)$ you give in the example doesn't have $f'(x)$ at $0$.

Comment: @DetectiveKing If you define $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra wow,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An extremely simple counterexample of (b) is
$$f(x)=x$$
$$g(x)=x+1.$$
Hence $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x+1}=0,$$ so $f(x)=o(g(x))$ as $x \to 0$;

but $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1}=1\not=0,$$ so $f'(x)\not=o(g'(x))$ as $x \to 0$.