# integration of small oh function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

In Exercise 1.5 of the book [Introduction to Perturbation Methods](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Perturbation_Methods.html?id=EX5iNglbqB4C&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false), we have the following,

---

Suppose $f=o(\phi)$ for small $\varepsilon$, where $f$ and $\phi$ are continuous.

$(a)$ Give an example to show that it is not necessarily true that
$$\int_0^\varepsilon f d\varepsilon'=o\left(\int_0^\varepsilon \phi d\varepsilon'\right)$$ 
 $(b)$ Show that 
$$\int_0^\varepsilon f d\varepsilon'=o\left(\int_0^\varepsilon \lvert\phi\rvert d\varepsilon'\right)$$

---

After some struggling with the related material, I come to understand that the question is easy for large $\varepsilon$ (*i.e.*, $\varepsilon\to\infty$), [as explained in this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934158/integration-and-little-o-notation).

As for small $\varepsilon$ (*i.e.*, $\varepsilon\to0$), I read something in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714040/does-the-little-oh-relation-remain-if-fx-and-gx-both-integrate-or-differ), but I am having a hard time figuring out the purpose of the absolute value there. Although I know that integral inequality needs that absolute value there, that does not help me find a counterexample.

The following is my **wrong** reasoning so far. Since $f=o(\phi)$ for small $\varepsilon$, that is
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{f}{\phi}=0$$

on the other hand, since both $f$ and $\phi$ are continuous, we have
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_0^\varepsilon f d\varepsilon'=0\qquad \text{and}
\qquad\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_0^\varepsilon \phi d\varepsilon'=0$$
Now by L'Hospital's Rule and chain rule, we have
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^\varepsilon f d\varepsilon'}{\displaystyle\int_0^\varepsilon \phi d\varepsilon'}=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{f}{\phi}=0$$

So could you help me point out what is wrong here? How does the absolute value sign come in here? Is the counterexample quite pathological? Many thanks!